# Change all $2^m$ bits to the same value with some restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $n$ bits $A_1, A_2,\cdots,A_n$ on a row $(n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2)$, each of them is either $0$ or $1$. For every second, the bit $A_i ~ (i=1..n)$ changes its value according to the following rule: If $A_{i-1}$ and $A_{i+1}$ has the same value with $A_i$ (i.e $A_{i-1}=A_i=A_{i+1})$ then $A_i$ is changes to $0$, otherwise it changes to $1$ (we always assume that $A_0=A_1$ and $A_n = A_{n+1}$ at any time). Proof that if $n=2^m$ for some positive integer $m$, there will always be a time that all the bits have value $0$.

For example with $n=4$ and the initial values of the bits are $(1,1,0,1)$, then we have:
$$(1,1,0,1) \rightarrow (0,1,1,1) \rightarrow (1,1,0,0) \rightarrow (0,1,1,0) \rightarrow (1,1,1,1) \rightarrow (0,0,0,0)$$

My attempt: We call a sequence "good" if it changes to all $0$s at some point. From what I've noticed, if a sequence of $2n$ bits is good then there should be a point where it becomes a palindrome (the first palindrome that appears in the above example is $(0,1,1,0)$) and the problem becomes proving an $n$ bits sequence is good. Unfortunately I had no idea of what to do next.

Comment: @MangoPizza Oops, my bad. If all the numbers are $1$ then in the next step they're all going to be $0$s anyway. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: For $m = 3$, consider $$(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0) \rightarrow (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1) \rightarrow (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0) \rightarrow (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1) \rightarrow (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)$$ which is a cycle.